# ConstraintLayout: Are constraints commutative?

Tags: java, android, android-constraintlayout

Assume I have a ConstraintLayout and two views V1 and V2.
Are constraints on V1 and V2 commutative? I.e. does

```
V1:
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/V2"
```

automatically imply

```
V2:
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/V1"
?
```

What if only one of these is set? What if both are set?
It seems logical that if a V1 is on top of V2 then V2 must be below V1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, the relative positions will be the same whether you constrain V1 to V2 or vice versa. However, your layout won't necessarily look the same.

When V1 is constrained to V2 (bottom to top), the bottom margin of V1 will be honored. If V2 is constrained to V1 (top to bottom), then V2's top margin will be honored.